# the function error in vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I write following in vs2010:

```
int test() const;
```

it tell me the `const` used incorrectly.and said:

> Non member function does not allow the use of type qualifier

I wonder why,does it the problem of vs?or how to use such function in vs?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: yes ,but it failed,don't know why

Comment: @DevilTour that didnt answer my question, we get it failed.. but you didnt say what you wanted to make it achieve

Comment: @BugFinder it just a test.There is the thing . I read the book of the

Comment: @bugfinder data structure it write function ,like my example,so why they  are different?

Answer (score 1):

`const` when applied to a function is only applicable to non-static member functions, not free functions or static member functions.

```
class A
{
    void f1() const;        // OK
    static void f2() const; // Not OK
};

void f3() const; // Not OK
```

From the C++ standard:

- *9.3.1 Nonstatic member functions*

> A non-static member function may be declared const, volatile, or const volatile.

- *9.4.1 Static member functions*

> A static member function shall not be declared const, volatile, or const volatile.

Answer (score 0):

const in that context means this method will not modify any member variables. If it is not a method of a class (i.e. it is a free floating function), then it has no meaning.

Comment: but in my <<data structure>>book ,it write like that,and it's not in a class, did he forget it?or beacause other things.

Comment: Maybe the author just zoomed into a method that is in reality part of a class.